# Arch Linux can't connect to x server

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xfce

After installing xfce, and all the x packages, it gives me multiple errors after trying to run startx, the first one is:

(EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
and then:
server terminated with error (1)
and then:
unable to connect to X server: connection refused

I'm using virtualbox, and this is my first time using arch linux, so I may have done something stupid.

Comment: You should explain the steps you did to get to that point (maybe the guide you were following).

Comment: I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwvHeFixpZY) guide. Which in turn was following the guide on the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow [these](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox) instructions

**try;**

**1. cleanup**

login as user to console

```
pacman -Q | grep box
```

`sudo pacman -R` all your current virtualbox stuff

**2. reinstall**

```
sudo pacman -Syy
sudo pacman -S virtualbox-guest-utils
```

select `virtualbox-host-modules-arch`

then the most important bit;

```
sudo systemctl enable vboxservice 
sudo reboot
```

login then `startx`

**still having issues?**

`lsmod` and check the listed modules from the arch wiki are loaded. especially vboxvideo
uninstall and try again with DKMS

try `sudo pacman -R virtualbox-guest-utils` and see if xfce will start. if does but the window is static resolution then probably something a miss with the video. ensure you havent installed intel drivers or something as a part of a physical computer install which might be interfering.

still nothing - start digging into the logs. the error message you see will refer to a `Xorg.0.log` which will be worth a look, and your dmesg for any errors with drivers on boot.

*edit:removed unnecessary package.*

Comment: Now is says: Server terminated successfully.

Comment: Oh, I had to run startxfce4, I guess now ill have to configure x to run xfce by default.  I think the problem was either that I installed intel video drivers or that I didn't install vbox-...-arch.  Thanks.

Comment: But, the window is static rez

Comment: if startx isnt working then "add exec startxfce4 to Xinitrc." [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xfce) if the windows is static and doesnt resize ensure you lsmod is showing the vboxvideo and check DKMS with your guest utilities isnt installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had to add an Xorg Configuration file.  I was configuring an Intel Graphics

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Xorg_configuration